# Moving from one activity to previous activity in android

Tags: android

I have activity1 and activity2 in a quiz app. activity1 shows the questions with answers to be selected and activity2 is a result screen in which i have list of question links. when a question link is clicked it should show the particular question view from activity1

Comment: Use intent to solve this problem.

Comment: @swetha welcome to SO..if you want to move 1 screen to another u can use Intent.Read this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Comment: You can use startActivityForResult concept if you are fully aware with how to use it, otherwise you can start activity A with clear top flag and start activity A again.

Comment: Please clear what you want and what is your problem dear...so that i can suggest you better..:)

Answer (score 0):

u can use this

```
  Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
  i.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message);
  startActivity(i);
```

in the activity B i get the info:

```
  String message = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```